# which chart can I use to make this? from highcharts

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart, stacked, stacked-area-chart, column-chart

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R9bA.png)
I want to make a chart like this, but don't know which chart to use.
Do you know which chart can I use from highcharts to make this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a [ribbon chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-ribbon-charts) and it doesn't look like highcharts has one of those.

They do have [stream graph](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/streamgraph), and a [sankey diagram](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sankey-diagram) which might get close enough.

Comment: thank you, I couldn't find which chart it is. You are right, it's a ribbon chart